# How to make absolute positioned DIV push content below it with slideDown()?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have a page that houses all of the body content within an old-school 960x wrapper. I need to add a banner into the middle of the page, but this banner needs to span the full width of the page. Not only that, but it has a show/hide accordion that uses `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`. So it needs to push the content below it down as it slides.

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvawzg8g/1/

The only way I can think of getting a child element of a wrapper to be full width of the page, where the wrapper has a set pixel width, is to use absolute positioning. When I do that, it ends up above or below the other page content and doesn't push it with `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

Comment: position it absolutely, add a "filler" in it's place, a div of the same height and when you toggle the accordion toggle the height of the filler div as well

Comment: I'm confused.  Doesn't your JSfiddle already do what you're describing?  Some sketches of your desired states might help.  Also, I'm not sure I see what your question is.

Comment: @SurrealDreams He wants the banner to span 100% of the window, yet it has to be located in the 960px container.

Comment: @PatsyIssa is correct. It is housed within the 960px wrapper, but itself has to be 100% page width. When it expands down, it should push the content below it down accordingly, not cover it up.

Comment: Told ya add a filler div, sec i ll make a demo

Comment: @user1729506 - thanks for clarifying about pushing content while animating the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the concept behind this is to fake the effect by having the banner positioned absolute and have an empty div right behind it that simulates it's place:

**The html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"><p>potatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotato</p></div>
    <div class="content">potatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotato</div>
    <div class="banner">banner</div>
    <div class="filler">filler</div>
    <div class="content">potatopotatopotatopotatopotatopotato</div>
    <div class="content">potatopotatopotatopotatopotato</div>
</div>
```

**The Css**

```
.container{
    width:960px;
    height:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.content{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.banner{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.filler{
    height:20px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.toggled{
    height:100px;
}
```

And **the js**:

```
$('.banner').on('click', function(){

    $('.filler, .banner').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLqy4p0u/)

Comment: I was easily able to adapt it to my code. Simple enough concept, and worked well on the final page. Thanks.